# First install of Linux I get an error!

Tags: system-installation

I get a message saying "BOOTMGR is missing". I have formatted the hard drive as it had Windows 7 on the machine and I wanted to delete it and start a fresh install of Ubuntu to check out how it works. Can you help since the OS will not start the install?

Comment: How are you trying to install Ubuntu?  What are you doing from the moment you reboot the computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

When you search [your problem](http://goo.gl/iFa6jQ) in google everything is about Windows so I think you frogot to delete the **System Reserved Partition** and your pc is trying to boot from there. Just delete it and your done.